# Find Which Object NSUndoManager is Acting On

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my app, users are able to quickly switch back and forth between objects and edit the text on those objects.

While they press "undo," I want to bring up the relevant object so they can see the undo they are performing.

The objects are instances of an `NSManagedObject` subclass, and I'm using the undo manager that comes with the `managedObjectContext` you get when you create a `UIManagedDocument`.

The undo & redo is functioning fine otherwise.

How can I tell which object is being 'undone' for a given undo operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out. The method I needed was:

- (void)awakeFromSnapshotEvents:(NSSnapshotEventType)flags

Which can be overridden in a subclass of NSManagedObject.

This method gets called whenever an object is affected by an undo or a redo. I was previously under the impression it only got called when an undo inserts or deletes an object, but it gets called if an object is changed as well.

What I do in this method is post a notification containing the objectID, then when I receive that notification, I go and find the object that corresponds with the objectID I received.

So in my NSManagedObject subclass, my awakeFromSnapshotEvents looks like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromSnapshotEvents:(NSSnapshotEventType)flags {
   NSManagedObjectID *thisID = self.objectID;
   NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:thisID forKey:@"noticeObjectID"];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"awakeFromSnapshotNotification" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

And in the receiver's viewWillAppear, I register for the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didAwakeManagedObject:) name:@"awakeFromSnapshotNotification" object:nil];
```

Finally, my receiver's `didAwakeManagedObject:` method looks like this. There's probably a better way to do this, but this works fine for me. I happen to be concerned about the index position of the object I need within an NSOrderedSet backed by Core Data, so I just iterate through the ordered set til I find the right one.

```
- (void) didAwakeManagedObject:(NSNotification*)notice {
   for (int i=0; i<project.orderedSet.count; i++) {
      if ([notice.userInfo objectForKey:@"noticeObjectID"] == [[project.orderedSet objectAtIndex:i] objectID]) {
         NSLog(@"%d IS EQUAL", i);
         return;
      }
   }
}
```